# Javac is not recognized even path is set

Tags: java

I have installed `Java development kit 8` on my Windows 64-bit hp pavilion laptop. I deleted system variable path and created a user variable path and set the value to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin`.

But I can't run javac on command prompt. How can I run java development kit 8?

I have watched many videos and read a few suggestion on this website but nothing is working for me.

Comment: javac is under jdk folder C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin

Answer (score 3):

You have installed a JRE, not a JDK.  The JRE is just the bare minimum and does not include "javac".

Download a JDK instead and repeat what you did.

Comment: nice kunne se svar fra en dansker. hygge ;)

Comment: can send a link to install JDK?

Comment: just google it download java jdk 8 and you get http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: i downloaded the installer from the same url

Comment: Anything else in C:\Program Files\Java ?

Comment: The JRE and JDK download pages look very similar.

Answer (score -1):

Add java root folder\bin to System Variable path and it will work. Why delete the PATH variable should have appended it